# why backslash is added when I pass the value from Jquery to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

When I pass a value from Jquery (For Example `test's` name) in post method.When I get the the same value in PHP and return it I got like this
`test\'s` name.I don't know why?
I used the encode URI also.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code? If you use encode and were already passing it as an object for example, it'll get double encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hoster doesn't permit you to change a php configuration, you can use this function for POST, GET.. arrays.

```
<?php
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}
if((function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc())    || (ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase') && (strtolower(ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase'))!="off")) ){
    stripslashes_deep($_GET);
    stripslashes_deep($_POST);
    stripslashes_deep($_COOKIE);
}
?>
```

Comment: Ya it is remove the magic Quotes.Thanks for everyone for your quick responses.Now I got the little bit knowledge on this and solved my problem.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

You must have magic quotes option turned on in your php.

Try to set

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

in your configuration.

Comment: Whether is it possible to `magic_quotes_gpc = Off` in run time

Comment: Then you need to put in place precautions to make your websites/applications more portable. `$value = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? stripslashes($value) : $value;` does the trick.